# How to check if an positive integer can be represented as a sum of integers

Tags: algorithms, integers

How to determine if an integer x > 0 can be represented as 20n + 50m + 100k, where n,m,k >= 0 and are integers.

Comment: For *big* x, this looks trivial: What about 110? What is the biggest multiple of 10 that can't be represented? Does fixing $k=0$ change anything?

Comment: Ok,  I can always get 100k so this means my problem scope is (0, 100).

Comment: (0, 20) No; 20 Yes; <21, 39) No; 40 Yes; <41, 49) No; 50 Yes; <51, 59) No; 60 yes; <61, 69) No, 70 Yes, <71, 79) No; 80 Yes; <81,89) No ; 90 yes; <91, 99) No.

Comment: @greybeard thank you :)

Comment: Given that $100=5\cdot20$ (also $100=2\cdot50$), the third term is redundant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you:) it is

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear combinations of $20$ and $50$ with non-negative coefficients are

$$0,20,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,\cdots$$

Hence all $x$ multiples of $10$ will work, except $10$ and $30$.

Answer (score 0):

The greatest common divisor of 20, 50 and 100 is gcd(20, 50, 100) = 10. All multiples of 10 can be found as the sum of (positive or negative) multiples of 20, 50, or 100, and no other integers can. However, some numbers might require negative multiples, for example 10 = 1 * 50 - 2 * 20.

If x and x+10 are a sum with positive integers, then so are x + k*10 for all k ≥ 0, because you add x + (k/2) * 20 if k is even, and (x + 10) + ((k-1) / 2) * 20 if k is odd.

You find easily that 10 and 30 are not sums with positive integers, but 20, 40 and 50 are, and we saw that with 40 and 50 all other numbers created by adding a multiple of 10. The solution is

```
{ k * 10: k ≥ 2 and k ≠ 3 }.
```

In general, you would calculate the gcd g of the numbers (in this case gcd (20, 50, 100) = 10). You state that only integers of the form k * g (in this case k * 10) can be solutions, then divide everything by g.

Now the problem is for example "Which integers k > 0 are the sum of 2a + 5b + 10c, a, b, c ≥ 0", and since these numbers have a gcd of 1, there is always a solution in (possible negative) integers. Let m be the smallest of these numbers, in this case m = 2. If we find integers k to k + m - 1 with non-negative coefficients, then we can increase a by 1, 2, 3 etc. to find solutions for all the larger k. So we try to find solutions for k = 1, 2, 3 etc. until we find m consecutive k with solutions, and then we know all solutions.